# android print and zebra ticket with 220 ms

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app, and I need to print ticketing.

my tools are:
Zebra MZ220 printer
ZebraDesigner v2
eclipse

in connecting the printer, and print test pages.

but my problem comes when I want to bring the format of the label set.

I created one called etiqueta.lbl label, and when I want to pick up this format in android, I get read but I get the name of etiquet.fmt and fields which introduces the labels do not appear in android, not as read correctly.

I have installed zebra utilities and sample code provided, but does not say anything

thanks

**UPDATE: I'm working with bluethooth**  ,¿they could work with this printer with xml?

**UPDATE 03/10/2013 09:01 ::
  printer.getFormatUtil().getVariableFields("utf8");
                FieldDescriptionData[] variables = printer.getFormatUtil().getVariableFields(new String(formatContents, "utf8"));**

**and so is the object**
[image]

**and this is the identifier we introduce in the zebra D Design**
[image]

**as I can do to vega not null and if the name I choose?**

**Yes, this is my code:**

```
 byte[] formatContents = printer.getFormatUtil().retrieveFormatFromPrinter(sFormato);
              printer.getFormatUtil().getVariableFields("utf8");
              FieldDescriptionData[] variables = printer.getFormatUtil().getVariableFields(new String(formatContents, "utf8"));
```

**there any way to create a dynamic list?**

**UPDATE 07/10/2012:** in the end this is what happened:

the two response helped me a lot,I created a small class that I printed with the printer language, CPCL not support other. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you export the label from ZebraDesigner? Is it CPCL or ZPL? Do the built in format labels in ZebraUtilities work for your printer?

An MZ220 is a CPCL printer, so you need to give it CPCL. The saved `.lbl` file from ZebraDesigner is NOT ready to go for a printer, you need to export the label as CPCL and feed that to the printer

Answer (score 1):

This article explains how to use ZebraDesigner to save a format to an MZ-printer: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8141&actp=LIST.  Notice that you only have to follow steps 1 and 2 in that article.  Step 3 is useful if you want to test-print your format OUTSIDE of Android, but it is not useful for testing within Android.

Once you follow steps 1 and 2 above, the Zebra Utilities Android app should see the format and allow you to recall it and print it with user-data.

Comment: ok, esto es muy útil. pero mi problema sigue siendo el mismo. No puedo elegir el texto android objeto identifie.

Comment: fieldName property is still coming to null,

Comment: Aqui esta ejemplo Android usando el SDK: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA278&actp=RSS.  En este ejemplo no se extrae los nombres de los variables - nada mas se los manda a imprimir.

Comment: Can you show the Android code that you are using to recall the variables?  Also, send the following command to your printer and read the response:

! U1 getvar "file.dir" <<<<<enter/carriage return here>>>>>

This should give you a list of files.  Once you see your format, send this command and paste it:

! U1 setvar "file.type" "YOURFILE.FMT"

This will let us see the contents of the format on the printer.